# Does Apple have access to the cryptographic keys to decrypt Safari Sync Data?

Tags: ios, macos, synchronization, safari, apple

I was reading over [iOS's security guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf), and it is unclear to me whether Apple can accessed synced Safari data. For example, if Apple received a FISA Order for all information on iCloud on all customers, would they have the ability to reveal a user's web browsing history?

I know that passwords are stored in your keychain which Apple configured in a way where not even they can access it, what about browsing history and synced tabs?